# Refreshing a lookup field value after key value change

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, lookupfield

I have a two tables :

- `DEPARTMENTS` (Index, Name)
- `EMPLOYEES` (Index, Name, DEPID, DepName)

`DepName` is a lookup value which retrieve `DEPARTMENTS.Name` using `DEPID` which references `DEPARTMENT.Index`.

When using a DBGrid displaying the `EMPLOYEES` table, and after changing `DEPID` value, the record's `DepName` is not updated and do not reflect the change until I re-run the query!

Is there anyway to do this and get the lookup value reflect the change live ?

- Rad Studio XE Tokyo,
- Firebird 3.0,
- FireDac components (TFDQuery),

Comment: Where DEPID is changed - in DataSet or in DB table? If you retrieve data from EMPLOYEES with SELECT with JOINs - simplest way is to rerun the query.

Comment: I never liked how DBGrid work. That is why I always use a StringGrid instead and do all related database stuff in methods of a DataModule. This separate data presentation (user interface, grid) and data model (data module) which makes the program much more clear, easy to understand and maintainable. I use events in the grid to refresh it according to the user actions. Of course I manage to not rerun the query which fill all the table, only a small query to fetch data for a modified cell.

Comment: `When using a DBGrid displaying the EMPLOYEES table, and after changing DEPID value` this is made for table-like "ISAM" data storages. Like Excel, etc. Without transactions, without query languages, etc. This is really different from client-server model. Mayby you need "briefcase" approach, you make a smal lcopy of relevant database information, edit it, and then try to upload ALL the changes into the database. Granted, this increases chance of "obsolete data" collisions. `TClientDataSet` and its friends from `DataSnap/MIDAS` family were made to implement this model in Delphi

Comment: Same problem here, whith no DBGRID involded.  I do have a TFDQuery with a lookup field, and when I change the key value, the lookup field remains.  No ISAM system, Postgres database and It works fine in many other TFDQueries.  I tried TFIELD.RefreshLookupList with no improve.  Doesn't throw any error, it recovers one value for the lookupfield, but not the value that corresponds to the key field.

Comment: The problem I had was when inserting on the TFDQuery (FDQ_Detail), and informing the key field, the lookup field wouldn't follow that key.  I did FDQ_Detail.Post and the lookup field refreshed correctly.  In order to keep on Editing  the record I did FDQ_Detail.Edit right the way and it worked.  I don't put it as the answer as certainly does look like an odd way to do it.  BUT IT DID WORK.

Comment: "  JOINs are performed on the server.  When you simply change the lookup
key in your drop-down, you haven't asked the server to do anything.
Only when you Post (if ForceRefresh is TRUE) or Refresh in some way will
a new SELECT be issued.  "

Answer (score 0):

If you can do EMPLOYEES.Post the lookupfield should refresh correctly.  In order to keep on Editing the record you can do EMPLOYEES.Edit back again.  It is probably not the right way to do it but it did work for me.

You can try CalcField.RefreshLookupList that looks like the accurate way to do it, but it didn't work for me on Delphi XE6 with firedac against Postgres database with cached updates.